# Set @ sign as a string attribute in android.

Tags: android, xml, resources

I'm using the @ sign in a project and want to set its text value to a string resource. However android studio complains if i do this.
`<string name="atsign">@</string>`. What is the best way to set the @ sign as a string attribute?

Comment: `<string name="atsign">\@</string>`

Comment: <string name="atsign">\@</string>

Comment: `<string name="atsign">@</string>` works fine although AS is complaining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this below code in your string.xml file

```
<string name="at_str">\u0040</string>

Output
```

[image: This is the output from my app]

Answer (score 1):

use this as your string value

\@